# Forward reference and recursion

Tags: java, recursion, reference

Why is it possible for a variable to call (initialise itself) a method that calls the same variable (seems a recursion)? I expected to see an endless recursion, but it compiles without errors. Any explanation?

```
class Forward {
     static int test(){
         return i;
     }
     static int i=test();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(test()); //sout= 0
        System.out.println(i);      //sout =0
    }

}
```

Another example. Why does referencing `Backwards.j` work while referencing `j` gives an error("illegal forward reference"):

```
class Backwards{

    //static int i=j;  //illegal forward reference;  
    static int i=Backwards.j;  //reference through class works
    static int j=i;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you understand the answers?

Answer (score 5):

If you step through the code in your debugger you will see that `i = test();` is only run once ever.

The previous value for `i` is `0` and that's the value `test()` returns before `i` has been initialised.

The java compiler can't detect every possible forward reference, only the simplest ones.